# Linking to C++ files

Tags: c++

I have written  mathematica file that does manipulations on a certain set of points. I would like to access code that someone else has written for a least square fit in C++. How do I access this C++ in mathematica?

Some specifics about the code: The least square fit code is a function that accesses a .cpp file and two different .h files. It is a void function that takes in a vector of points, the point itself, and an integer, each called by reference.

I make this specific because I am a novice in coding in c++. I have seen in another post someone say that they have :

I think we have these:

MathLink 
communication through pipes/files 
LibraryLink

I do not have any of those things, nor do I know what they are. Can someone explain how a novice like myself can handle this situation.

Also, from what I saw from other posts, the function I have to access is much more complicated. It looks something like:

void function1(vectorFoo &thing, Foo &variable1, int64_t &variable2)
    {

```
    stuff happens here
}
```

(the the first argument of the function is a vector that takes in Foo between "<" and ">" but that formatting won't let me show that. that's why I wrote "vectorFoo")

this function accesses other functions,call them "function2", "function3", and other named variables (if that is the right technical term...like I said, I don't know much c++) from three files. so even if I call this file, will I have to worry about calling the other three files from which it draws? Please help!

Comment: Regardless of the accepted answer there, today, generally the best way is LibraryLink.

Comment: You're aware that Mathematica knows all about least squares fits (and other types of fits)?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: I am aware about Mathematica's least square capabilities. They are not suitable for my purposes. I saw the other post about implementing C++ files on Mathematica, but the person who posted the question seems to have more of a setup than I do. I am starting from ground zero.

Comment: "They are not suitable for my purposes." - can you explain why?

Comment: i am not fitting to a line but a circle

Comment: "I do not have any of those things, nor do I know what they are." <-- then you need to start by looking them up.  The linked question has detailed answers for explaining some of these.  Calling C from Mathematica is not trivial, and it is going to take some time to learn it.  The linked question has the basics, plus links to the documentation.  *That's where you need to start.*  First learn the basics, using simple examples.  When you're comfortable with that, only then move on to solving your more complicated problem.

Comment: If you have problems understanding the answers in the linked question, you need to ask specific questions about the things that you had trouble with instead of a general one about how to call C++ from Mathematica.  The general question is already answered in the other thread, in as much detail as possible on this site.

Comment: "but a circle" - this is doable in *Mathematica*. Search around here; there have been at least two questions about circle fitting on this site.

Comment: The following one-liner with a list of your coordinate pairs as input in the variable `pts` finds the circle parameters for you: `NMinimize[{((#1 - mx)^2 + (#2 - my)^2 - r^2)^2 & @@@ pts // Total,  mx > 0 && my > 0 && r > 0}, {mx, my, r}]`

Comment: so if my list of points is 

points = {{x1,y1},{x2,y2},{x3,y3},...}

then I should write

NMinimize[{((#1 - points[[i]][[1]])^2 + (#2 - points[[i]][[2]])^2 - r^2)^2 & @@@ pts // Total, points[[i]][[1]] > 0 && points[[i]][[2]] > 0 && r > 0}, {points[[i]][[1]], points[[i]][[2]], r}]

What do I put for #1, #2, and r, given that I only have a list of points?

Comment: All you have to do is set `pts` to your list of points before running @Sjoerd's snippet.

Comment: Indeed, *don't change anything in the code I posted*. Just start with `pts ={{1,0},{0.7,0.71}, ... ,{-1,0}}` or whatever your data may be. Then execute the above code as is. The result will be the circle's center given by `mx` and `my` and its radius `r`.

Comment: Alternatively, if you have your points in a differently named variable change the variable `pts` in my code to the one you're using (apparently, `points`). That's the *only change needed* in that case.